# How to describe "thread safety" in the context of child processes?

Tags: software

I'm writing a software application that spawns several child processes in order to process tasks concurrently.

Each child process has access to shared data structures, and it is very important that the processes don't interfere with each other when accessing/modifying these structures.

If the application used **threads** instead of **processes** to achieve concurrency, then we would describe this consideration as **thread safety**:

> A piece of code is **thread-safe** if it manipulates shared data structures only in a manner that guarantees safe execution by multiple threads at the same time.

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety))

However, since this application uses **processes** instead of **threads**, what term should I use instead of "thread safety"?

Comment: You might say something like "concurrency-safe".

Comment: OT, but is this a good idea? Normally you'd want a single process to own the memory, and communicate changes through that thread-safe process. Otherwise you'll have trouble scaling, and be limited to a single machine for execution (not very cloud friendly).

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)):

> The implementation of threads and processes differs between operating systems, but in most cases a thread is a component of a process.

If your processes are running on a typical computer, in your example each concurrent process can be said to *contain a single thread*.

So the phrase you're looking for is probably still **thread-safe**.

Answer (score -1):

May be **scaled-out** via multiple processes

> To **scale horizontally (or scale out/in)** means to add more nodes to (or remove nodes from) a system, such as adding a new computer to a distributed software application.
>   - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability

Comment: That has nothing to do with being concurrency-safe.